# Are the two legitimate ways to factor out $\alpha$ in the equation $v_0cos(\alpha)t=x$?

Tags: trigonometry

The first one would be $\alpha=\arccos(\frac{x}{tv_0})$ and the second one $\alpha=\frac{1}{v_0}\arccos\frac{x}{t}$ .

Ok, I figured out, why it makes sense. Whether you write $cos(\frac{\pi}{2})$ or $\frac{1}{2}cos(\pi)$ the outcome is the same ...

Ok, that was wrong for reasons explained below.

Comment: Try plugging some numbers that work for the original equation into each of your proposed solutions -- for example $v_0=2$, $\alpha=\pi/3$, $t=1$, $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, no we do NOT have $\cos(\pi/2)=\cos(\pi)/2$ and in general

$$\cos(ax)\neq a\cdot \cos x.$$

Henning shows how to show that one of your formula is incorrect. To just find the correct answer proceed as follows:

$$\begin{align}
v_0\cdot\cos(\alpha)\cdot t&=x
\\ \underset{v_0t\neq 0}{\Rightarrow}\cos\alpha&=\frac{x}{tv_0}
\\ \underset{0\leq \alpha\leq\pi}{\Rightarrow}\alpha&=\arccos\left(\frac{x}{tv_0}\right). 
\end{align}$$

Comment: Is there a rule that says $\alpha=\frac{1}{v_0}\arccos\frac{x}{t}$ is wrong?

Comment: What the hell is a rule? As Henning suggested (and you ignored), let $v_0=2$, $\alpha=60^\circ$, $t=1$ and $x=1$. Then $v_0\cos(\alpha)t=x$ reads $2\cdot\cos(60^\circ)\cdot 1=1$ which is correct because $\cos(60^\circ)=\frac12$ so the values suggested by Henning satisfy the original equation. Now using these values $\frac{1}{v_0}\arccos(x/t)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\arccos(1)$. But $\arccos(1)=0$ so $\frac{1}{v_0}\arccos(x/t)=\frac{1}{2}0=0$ but this is NOT equal to $\alpha=60^\circ$ so that formula couldn't be correct.